# WordPress PHP, why esc_like method is needed for LIKE type of query?

Tags: php, wordpress, sql-injection

So I'm left a little confused why on WordPress there is a method like esc_like():
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/esc_like/
The advice is that parameter that will be used by LIKE must be escaped with esc_like() to make it safe, like this:

```
$wild = '%';
$find = 'only 43% of planets';
$like = $wild . $wpdb->esc_like( $find ) . $wild;
$sql  = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_content LIKE %s", $like);
```

But why:

```
$sql  = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_content LIKE %s", $like);
```

Wouldn't be enough in this case to properly prepare that LIKE parameter? I don't understand where it could go wrong witout using esc_like and is it really that something can cause vulnerability if used without that esc_like method.

To my understanding $wpdb->prepare should be enough, but lately learning about this I'm not sure.

So the main question is, does it impose very serious security risk if I use it without $wpdb->esc_like() method?

Comment: From that document page, look at the source. It is just add C slashes to `%`, `_`, ``\\``. That means it will be escape something like `43%` in search keyword.

Comment: I am afraid you just confused something.  the page you linked to says quite the opposite, "The output is **not** SQL safe" (emphasis mine). So, nowhere this page claims this function makes anything "safe". Just more convenient and predictable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that for preventing SQL injection you have to use a query parameter.

The purpose of "escaping" a string for LIKE isn't the same purpose as preventing SQL injection.

The `%` and `_` characters are wildcards in a LIKE expression. But what if you want to match those characters literally?

SQL provides a solution:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

> To test for literal instances of a wildcard character, precede it by the escape character.

The default escape character is `\`.

Comment: Gentlemen, please see my answer. WordPress's SQL driver API handles this escaping strangely. It's best to use it as provided rather than do the escaping ourselves for these LIKE constants, or things can break.

Comment: Well, I'm looking at the doc and the code here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/esc_like/ I see that the usage example shows combining it with a prepared query, but I think that's only to show the proper order in which to apply it, _if_ you use it in a prepared query.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress uses a unique and incompletely documented scheme for doing `$wpdb->prepare()` processing. Display some SQL prepared that way and you'll see what I mean -- long uniqueid strings appear, and are later straightened out during the `->execute()` phase.

`->esc_like()` is part of that scheme. And, of course a lot of this is in aid of injection prevention.

Comment: I disagree. esc_like() has little to do with injection prevention. Just some unexpected results prevention.

Answer (score 0):

You must escape it if the value it's a user input or taken from a database or $SERVER global variable.
I use it this way:

```
$post_id = $wpdb->get_var(
                $wpdb->prepare(
                    "SELECT ID from {$wpdb->prefix}posts     WHERE post_name LIKE %s LIMIT 1", 
                    '%' . $wpdb->esc_like( $basename ) . '%'
                )
            );
```